# Return Ajax data to variable in jQuery on x-editable plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to assign the *source* value using ajax. But I'm not sure how.

The original code below is from: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#select

```
<a href="#" id="status" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Select status"></a>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#status').editable({
        value: 2,    
        source: [
              {value: 1, text: 'Active'},
              {value: 2, text: 'Blocked'},
              {value: 3, text: 'Deleted'}
           ]
    });
});
</script>
```

I've change the example above to this below trying to use ajax to assign the returned value to *source*.

```
$('.settings-loc').editable({
    type: 'select',
    source: $.get( "../../ajax/_source.php" ),
    url: '../../ajax/_settings.php',
});
```

My php ajax file is as below:

```
$test = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT id AS value, customer_name AS text FROM customer_profile") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$emparray = array();
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($test))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
```

I'm actually just trying to return the `json_encode($emparray)` to the source variable in jquery.

However using `$.get( "../../ajax/_source.php" )` does not return the php value.

Comment: definitely not, without the answer below I wouldn't think of this way to write it. And its using a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $.get( "../../ajax/_source.php", function(data){
           $('.settings-loc').editable({
               type: 'select',    
               source: data,
               url: '../../ajax/_settings.php',
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks! this totally solved my problem and I've learned a new thing today!